# Convert time data to local time in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, datetimeoffset

I've read a few posts about similar subjects but nothing seems to answer this question. My database has the following information about a time

- Day of the week (a number between 0-6)
- Time (a number of milliseconds since midnight in the users local time)
- UTC offset ( number of hours different to UTC )
- DST Observed (boolean stating if DST is observed in that time zone)

This data represents opening hours. So there is a time for each day. I want to display that time in the users local time making the assumption that each day is in the future

```
int dayOffset = availability.Day - (int)now.DayOfWeek
if (dayOffset < 0)
    dayOffset += 7;
```

I'm really struggling to get my head around time zones and handling when one time zone might be observing DST while another maybe DOES observe DST but hasn't yet.
My main issue at the moment is I *think* I need to create a `DateTimeOffset` object for the non-local time but I'm not sure how to do that as I don't know if DST is in effect or not.
I hope I'm making myself clear. It really is a mind-bending experience working with dates and time!

Comment: Have you already tried Quartz.NET? It has ChronExpressions, which may help you out calculating the opening times. Also, take a look at this link: http://www.cronmaker.com/

Comment: The main issue I see is that you only have information about whether the time zone uses DST, but not information about when it is active. It will thus be impossible for you to know whether the DST should be used or not.

Comment: @Conyc: If the OP runs its system on an operational system configured with the client's local timezone, he can easily and correctly transform UTC time to local time.

Comment: @Conyc If I assume that the time for "Friday" is the next Friday from now then I have a date and I can surely know if DST will be in effect on that date

Comment: The problem isn't that you won't know if DST will be in effect in the local time that you wish to display the time in. The problem is that the original time data is stored in local time without information about when DST is in effect. You have to remember that different countries change to and from DST at different times.

Comment: @RealWorld To illustrate the problem, let me give you an example. You have the follow information stored: Day of week: 1, Time: 10:00, Offset: 0, DST: true. Then let's imagine that the current date is 2018-05-20. How can you tell if the information you have stored is meant to be 2018-05-21 10:00 UK time or Moroccan time? Both countries use UTC+0 with DST and both start and end DST at the same time usually, but Morroco does not use DST at the time of the Ramadan.

Comment: @Conyc but if I work from 9-5 in whatever time zone I reside then I work from 9-5 whether DST is in effect or not. The time only changes when its compared to another timezone. For clarity, the DST bool is set for the time zone not the time. So its not a bool saying whether DST is in effect, it's a bool that says whether DST is observed

Comment: @RealWorld Yes, but the issue is that your structure does not contain information about which timezone the data origins from. It only contains the UTC offset. If we use your example and combine it with my previous example, then the issue remains that on 2018-05-21, 9-5 in the UK is not the same as 9-5 in Morroco, even though they have the same base UTC offset, and both timezones use DST. But on that date DST is in effect in the UK, while it is not in effect in Morroco.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated by other answers, the usual solution to handling `DateTime` across time zones would be to store UTC times.

However, considering that you are not referencing an absolute time at a specific date, but instead are referring to a time at an infinite number of days in a specific time zone; storing the time as an UTC time doesn't make sense anymore, since the UTC time (even if we discard the date) would be different depending on the date, due to DST.

The best way to store the time is fairly close to what you have done already.

Your problem is that the time zone information you are storing at the moment is ambiguous, as it does not refer to a **specific** time zone, but instead refers to **properties** of the time zone.

To solve this problem, simply store the time zone identifier instead of the UTC offset and DST boolean.

It is now possible for us to construct the `DateTime` object and convert it to any time zone by using the [TimeZoneInfo class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo(v=vs.110).aspx):

```cs
int dayOffset = availability.Day - (int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek;
if (dayOffset < 0)
{
    dayOffset += 7;
}

var openingHourStart = DateTime
                       .SpecifyKind(DateTime.Today, DateTimeKind.Unspecified)
                       .AddDays(dayOffset)
                       .AddMilliseconds(availability.Time);

var sourceTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(availability.TimeZoneId);
var userTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.Local;

var convertedOpeningHourStart = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(openingHourStart,
                                                         sourceTimeZone,
                                                         userTimeZone);
```

Comment: If I store the C# TimeZone ID into the database then this solution works perfectly. Thanks for your help and patience :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be leveraging `DateTime.ToLocalTime()` and `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc()` in C# - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolocaltime(v=vs.110).aspx.

If you want to store only times that you're open from Monday to Sunday, fine. Have a simple data table to describe only the time for each day (0 = Sunday through 7 = Saturday -- this is .Net's `DayOfWeek` enumeration). Your lookup table might look like:

```
0  null
1  08:00:00
2  08:00:00
3  08:00:00
4  08:30:00
5  08:30:00
6  10:30:00
```

(Use whatever data type works for you--SQL Server 2008+ has a TIME data type, for example. Null can be used for Closed on that day--i.e., no open time.)

When it comes time to display YOUR time to any other user, use must create your UTC time on-the-fly at the moment you are displaying information to the local user.

Conyc provided one approach. My approach uses simple date/time strings. To use my approach, just store time values per day in your database. Then you can look up the open time for any given day. To express that time for another user in any locale, use this code to convert your time to UTC (you can substitute the "08:00:00 AM" string value with a string variable that you populated after looking up the open time in your database):

```
var StoreOpenTimeInUtc = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(Convert.ToDateTime("08:00:00 AM"));
```

To look up the open time in your database for a *particular day in the future*, you will need to concatenate the date to your time value, like this:

```
var StoreOpenTimeInUtc = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(Convert.ToDateTime("04/28/2018 08:00:00 AM"));
```

Once you have an accurate `StoreOpenTimeInUtc` variable, you can use that as the UTC value on someone else's machine who is anywhere else on planet earth. To convert that UTC value to their local time, use the .NET ToLocalTime() method:

```
var OpenTimeForLocalUser = StoreOpenTimeInUtc.ToLocalTime();
```

Note that this approach requires you to store only the open times as shown above. You don't have to worry about dates, local offsets from UTC, or anything else. Just leverage `ConvertTimeToUtc()` and `ToLocalTime()` as shown.

Comment: But this doesn't work, does it? I first need to construct a DateTime object in the timezone of the time stored in the database. How can I do that from a time and an offset that may or may not be observing DST on a particular date?

Comment: @Real World: If it's your database, don't you have the option of revising the data so that you're storing a pure UTC date-time value rather than your own variation of same? If you've inherited a database and must deal with these four columns then let us know. My advice is to store only a UTC date value and derive day, DST, time locally from that UTC value as you require.

Comment: It's my system yes so it could be changed but I can't store dates because they are times for each day of the week. A full date doesn't make sense. I work from 9am-5pm on a Monday for example. I work the same times locally regardless of DST but another users perception of my time is different depending on whether they are observing DST or not

Comment: Boiling it down: The only way to do what I call "time arithmetic" is to use UTC on both sides of the equation. Thus, the date is indeed relevant and thus makes sense. If you work 9-5 on Monday, we need to know *which* Monday you're talking about in order for anyone else on planet earth to know what 9AM means to you relative to their local time on the day in question. You must get your times in a UTC format in the database and then you can express that in anyone's local time. The date matters because that not only drives DST--and DST start/end dates are different across the world.

Comment: I get that, but the time for Monday is the same for all Mondays so the date is only relevant on the client side when I need to display the time for the coming Monday. The alternative is I store a time for every single day of the year in the database.

Comment: OK. See my addition to the original answer.

Comment: @Jazimov Storing a UTC time does not work when you need to represent the same local time independent on whether DST is in effect or not (it will result in two different UTC times). 9 AM in the UK when DST is not in effect will be 09:00 UTC, but 9 AM in the UK when DST **is** in effect will be 10:00 UTC. You cannot store one UTC time and have it represent both.

Comment: @Jazimov But your answer says "The key is to store all time as UTC time", which makes it seem like you are suggesting that the author should store the time as a UTC time.

Comment: @Conyc: I edited my answer for clarity. You are entirely incorrect when you say that UTC time changes in the UK when DST is in effect vs when it is not in effect. UTC never changes--it always represents a global, current date-time value. It is a global standard. What changes is the UTC *offset*. If you store UTC values in a database then you always can express that value for a time-zone. To get the right time from UTC you must know the time-zone and whether that time-zone is observing DST. That's what functions such as `ToLocalTime` are designed to calculate.

Comment: @Jazimov No, of course UTC doesn't change when the UK uses DST. What I am saying is that the same local time is observed at different UTC times.  9 AM in the UK on 1 January 2018 was observed at UTC 2018-01-01T09:00:00+00:00, while 9 AM in the UK today was observed at UTC 2018-04-27T10:00:00+00:00 (or 2018-04-27T09:00:00+01:00 - it's two representations of the same point in time).  If you want to store a time representing 9 AM in the UK at any day of the year, you cannot do that with UTC, because which one do you store? T09:00:00+00:00 or T09:00:00+01:00? It depends on the time of year.

Comment: We actually agree: You don't store UTC with the UTC offset--that's asking for trouble. You store only a UTC time value. You then use a local time function to convert that UTC to the local time at that moment, or you use the time zone function you presented to convert that stored UTC value to a local time on a particular day and at a particular time. If you start with UTC, you can then convert that to the local time for any place on plant earth on any day and time and get the correct value. Starting with UTC is the key. Once again, it's the offsets that change, not the UTC value.

Comment: @Jazimov If you are so adamant that storing the time in UTC would work, then please do tell which value you would store that would represent 9 AM in the UK at any time of the year. As stated in my previous comment; it doesn't seem possible to me.

Comment: Didn't mean to imply that UTC values were stored in the database--I meant to imply that a UTC value must be leveraged before being able to express a particular locale's time accurately in another locale on a given date. In fact, my original example clearly showed that only times as strings were being stored in the database. In any event, I have revised my answer and I think it's much clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to [Quartz.NET](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/tutorial/index.html).

It implements evaluation of CronExpressions, and even triggers to fire events at the given time. It can evaluate the next time an event will occur. This may help you out calculating the opening times.

Also, take a look at the [cronmaker website](http://cronmaker.com): there you can understand the full potential of CronExpressions.

The [CronExpressionDescriptor](https://github.com/bradymholt/cron-expression-descriptor) is a DotNET library for transforming CronExpressions into human readable strings.

Another library which I haven't tried yet is [HangFire].(https://www.hangfire.io/)

In this [forum post](https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/need-local-time-instead-of-utc/279/7) you can find some discussion on how HangFire implements evaluation of RecurringJobs in local timezone with DST, which I believe is a solution for what you are looking for.

Comment: Can you please explain how triggering events at a given time has any relevance to the OP question?

Comment: @Jazimov: I'm explaining the potential of the library. Definitively it deserves a chance, I've already implemented a reliable system with similar requirements to the OP's with this nice library.

Comment: @Jazimov: The local time offset is just one of the OP's datetime mind-blowing problems.

Answer (score 0):

A comment to another answer made the problem a little bit more clear.

So, first and foremost, do store only UTC in your database. Really.

Now, since you are not interested in the actual dates, since you are storing working schedules that repeat weekly, the date only becomes relevant once you want to *present* your times - and when you put them in your database.

So let's first see how you get your times into your database correctly. I'm assuming a user will enter times in their own locale.

Make sure you first create a (localised) `DateTime` consisting of the *current* date and the given time (from the user), and transform that to a UTC `DateTime` (you can keep the current date, it doesn't matter):

```
var utcDateTime = DateTime.Now.Date
                 .AddHours(userHours)
                 .AddMinutes(userMinutes)
                 .ToUniversalTime();
```

Now when you are presenting these times to the user, simply go the other way:

```
var userDateTime = DateTime.Now.Date
                  .AddHours(utcDateTime.Hour)
                  .AddMinutes(utcDateTime.Minute)
                  .ToLocalTime();
```

And then you can use the `userDateTime.Hour` and `.Minute` for display purposes.